# Pandas MultiIndex: Divide all columns by one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `results` of the form

```
                  TOTEXPPQ      TOTEXPCQ     FINLWT21
year quarter                                         
13   1        9.183392e+09  5.459961e+09  1271559.398
     2        2.907887e+09  1.834126e+09   481169.672
```

and I was trying to divide all (the first two) columns by the last one. My attempt was

```
weights = results.pop('FINLWT21')
results/weights
```

But I get

```
ValueError: cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping names
```

Which I don't get: There are overlapping names in the index:

```
weights.head()
year  quarter
13    1          1271559.398
      2           481169.672
```

Is there perhaps a better way to do this division? Do I *need* to reset the index?

Answer (score 27):

You have to specify the axis for the divide (with the [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) method):

```
In [11]: results.div(weights, axis=0)
Out[11]:
                 TOTEXPPQ     TOTEXPCQ
year quarter
13   1        7222.149445  4293.909517
     2        6043.371329  3811.807158
```

*The default is axis=1 and the result **columns** and weights' index names do not overlap, hence the error message.*

Comment: I just get `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 8), indices imply (4, 8)`. How do you map it to all columns?

Comment: @josh I suspect you want to use something that is size (8,) rather than (1, 8) ?